# Create responsive slide using Swiper JS in Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, swiper.js

I'd like to use swiper JS slide breakpoint in Angular 11 so different screen size breakpoints will have different total slidesPerView, I've read this documentation from Swiper JS https://swiperjs.com/angular and install swiper js from https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper

but I don't know how to implement responsive breakpoint in the component ts file. I've tried to implement this code below but the swiperConfig is not working.

Here is the HTML code

```
 <swiper>
          <ng-template [swiperSlide]="swiperConfig"  *ngFor="let item of items">
            <div class="list-item">
                <app-item></app-item>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
 </swiper>
```

Here is the TS Code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-swiper-test',
  templateUrl: './swiper-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./swiper-test.component.scss']
})
export class SwiperTestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  public swiperConfig = {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 20,
    breakpoints:{
      992:{
           slidesPerView: 4, 
          }
   }
  } 
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It's always nice to share an answer found (but you can actually post an answer on your own questions). Take care ... .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**### Update**

I've solved the problem

Here is the **html code**

```xml
<swiper [config]="swiperConfig">
    <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let item of items">
        <div class="list-item">
            <app-item></app-item>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</swiper>
```

Here is the **TS code**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Swiper from 'swiper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-swiper-test',
  templateUrl: './swiper-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./swiper-test.component.scss']
})
export class SwiperTestComponent implements OnInit {
  
    swiperConfig: any = {
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        spaceBetween: 20,
        breakpoints: {
            992: {
                spaceBetween: 20
            }
        }
    }

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: Hi..Which version of swiper did you use for Angular 11?